# yum --downloadonly ignores packages in local repo

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

I have two repos configured, one accessed via `baseurl=http://...` and one via `baseurl=file://...` (a local repo). When I run this command:

`sudo yum -y update --downloadonly --downloaddir=foo`

The command runs and lists many packages. However `foo` only contains packages from the remote repo not the local one. How do I 'download' the local files too?

What I am trying to do is pair down a local repo containing far more RPMs than I need down to just the ones I need to run an update. The idea being to create a new local repo containing only what I need.

Comment: yum normally does not distinguis between both repositories. He will just take the packages that have the highest version number. So either the packages in your local repo are older, either your local repository wasn't well configured. Did you try searching for your local packages using `yum` ?

Comment: @ChrisMaes the packages in the local repo are later versions. Searching using yum list shows versions in remote and local repos. If I `sudo yum install atop --downloadonly --downloaddir=./` which is not in the local repo, it downloads. If I try with curl which is in the local repo it does not download. If I don't use the downloadonly options, either package will actually install with no problems.

I.e. local repo is fine and yum must be coded to not download for repos with baseurl=file://

Comment: I suspect this is intended behaviour: https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/yum/__init__.py#L611

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed by reading the yum source code that this is intended, but annoying, behaviour.

The solution I found was:

In the repo file:

```
[local]
name=local
baseurl=http://localhost:9999
```

In Python:

```py
import http.server
import socketserver
import threading
os.chdir('/path to repo')
# We need the web server to run in its own thread
class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
  pass
httpd = ThreadedTCPServer(("127.0.0.1", 9999), http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd_thread = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
httpd_thread.daemon = True
httpd_thread.start()

...
yum stuff
...

httpd.shutdown()
httpd.server_close()
```